# R Mean of multiple groups by quartiles

Tags: r, group-by, mean, quartile

I have a dataframe with different variables, e.g.: x1, x2 and so on.
I created quartiles based on one variable (BE) with the following code:

```
Quantile_Var <- Var%>% mutate(Quartile = ntile(BE, 5))
```

Now I want to see the means of each variables (x1, x2...) by quartiles. I tried to use the following code, but it gives me too many information since I only need the means. How to edit the code so R only gives me the means?

```
Quantile_Testvar %>% split(.$quartile) %>% map(summary)`
```

It's probably completly easy, unfortunaly I have struggles to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use output from `ntile` as a group and get the average value for all the `x` variables.

```
library(dplyr)

Quantile_Var <- Var %>% 
                  group_by(Quartile = ntile(BE, 5)) %>%
                  summarise(across(starts_with('x'), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```